# Data fetching from Atlas Mongo with mongoose to angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have added one new input in my signup page which is name field and have changed settings in schema too. now how i can fetch that name to use in my post-list component and post-create component?

this is the syntax of created user. now i want to use this name at the place of post title.

```
{

  _id: 5eb54bb209a6c405e5fb5b97,

  name: 'chokko',

  email: 'chokko@test',

  password: '********************************'

}
```

**createUser.js**

```
exports.createUser = (req, res, next) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10).then((hash) => {
    const user = new User({
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hash,
    });
    user
      .save()
      .then((result) => {
        res.status(201).json({ message: "User created!", result: result });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res
          .status(500)
          .json({ message: "Invalid authentication credentials!" });
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: please add some minimum reproducible code or your attempt - thanks

Comment: exports.createUser = (req, res, next) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10).then((hash) => {
    const user = new User({
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hash,
    });
    user
      .save()
      .then((result) => {
        res.status(201).json({
          message: "User created!",
          result: result,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res
          .status(500)
          .json({ message: "Invalid authentication credentials!" });
      });
  });
};

Comment: edit your question instead of commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Model.findById(), to get specific document, with 'projection' to select fields (in this case 'name' field).

```
User.findById(id,'-id name')
```

Also, you have to explicitly remove _id ('-id') unless you want it to be returned with selected fields.